# I am not able to apply style attribute height to div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have written the following code. I want to make a div 'display: flex', and add two divisions, one with width:200px and one with width:100%;

```html
<div style="clear:both;display:flex; height: 100%;">
    <div style="width:400px; background-color: red;
        height:auto;">
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;
        background-color: black;
        height:auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

but I am not able to apply height to that div, it is showing 0 height in the developer option.

I have tried clear: both style, but still not working.

Please let me know the proper syntax and code, I am so confused in CSS.

Comment: your div's doesn't have any content so with height:auto; height results 0px. You can read this [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) or search on the internet you will find a lot of tutorials about css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all using inline styles is not a good ideea. They are very hard to read/edit and very hard to overwrite.

Second, you set height 100% on the parent div ( the one with display:flex ) . `height:100%` has to be relative to the height of a container. In your case `html,body` which don't have any height because you don't have any content.

Third, you set `height:auto` on the child div. `height:auto` is depending on the content of the element but you don't have any content.

My guess is that you want to have the parent div with height:100% of screen. You can use viewport height ( `100vh` ) or you can set a height of 100% to body,html like in the example below

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div style="clear:both;display:flex; height: 100%;">
  <div style="width:400px; background-color: red;
        height:auto;">
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%;
        background-color: black;
        height:auto;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

when you use of `auto`,it get height of content inside element.`div` have not content,so get height equal 0.

you can use of `min-height`:

```html
<div style="clear:both;display:flex; height: 100%;">
    <div style="width:400px; background-color: red;
        min-height:20px;">
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;
        background-color: black;
        height:auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

if you want use of `auto`,you must set `height` for `html` and `body` because you use of percent for `div` and it must be measured relative to his parents.

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
}
```

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div style="clear:both;display:flex; height: 100%;">
    <div style="width:400px; background-color: red;
        min-height:auto;">
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;
        background-color: black;
        height:auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Other way is use of unit `vh` like this:

```
<div style="width:400px; background-color: red; height:100vh;">
```

```html
  <div style="clear:both;display:flex;">
    <div style="width:400px; background-color: red;
        height:100vh;">
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;
        background-color: black;
        height:auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cover all the screen then you need to give your HTML tag height 100% and also height 100% to the body tag.

```html
<html style="height:100%;">
  <body style="height:100%;">
  <div style="clear:both;display:flex; height: 100%;">
    <div style="width:400px; background-color: red;
        height:auto;">
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;
        background-color: black;
        height:auto;">
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using `vh` you can set `height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100%`

```
height: 100vh;
```

```html
<div style="clear:both;display:flex; height: 100%;">
    <div style="width:400px; background-color: red;
        height:100vh;">
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;
        background-color: black;
        height:width;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that there is a more restrictive "heigth" attribute, that is, that the div is inside other tags. You can try to do the style in a .css file. It's much more how and best practice in HTML5. If you try just this code in a new html file, you can see that the div has a 100% heigth:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="clear:both;display:flex; height: 100%;">
    <div style="width:400px; background-color: red;
        height:auto;">
        Hello 1
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;
        background-color: black;
        height:auto;">
        Hello 2
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```